# What is the difference between “base64 -b0” in macOS versions prior to macOS 13 (Ventura) and “base64 -i” in macOS 13 (Ventura)?

Tags: macos, bash, mac

Up until I recently upgraded to macOS 13 (Ventura) I could run this Bash command to convert a JPEG image into a Base64 string in a script I occasionally use:

```
IMAGE_BASE64=$(base64 -b0 /path/to/image.jpg);
```

The resulting `IMAGE_BASE64` value could be used as the variable `$IMAGE_BASE64` in my script.

But I recently tried to use this script again in macOS 13 (Ventura) and this `base64` command was failing with the following error:

```
base64: invalid argument -b0
Usage:  base64 [-hDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

Switching the command to use `-i` seems to solve the issue:

```
IMAGE_BASE64=$(base64 -i /path/to/image.jpg);
```

But what is the difference between the two commands?

What was `-b0` doing previously prior to macOS 13 (Ventura) that `-i` is handling now in macOS 13 (Ventura)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will answer my own question.

Two “gotchas” grabbed me here and hopefully this answer will help someone in a similar position in the future:

1. The `-b0` needs to be set to `-b 0` nowadays.
2. The `-i` is now needed to indicate what the input file is.

So simply setting `-b0` in macOS 13 (Ventura) would never work. It needs to be `-b 0 -i`. More details below.

The `-b0` relates to line breaks and is the equivalent of `--break=0` which means that when that option is set to `0` line breaks are disabled which is what one wants for Base64 encoded binary image data; no line breaks!

Details found here in [this Mac OS X 10.7 man page for `base64`](https://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/man/base64.html) as well as the man page for `base64` which states:

```
The following options are available for base64:

-b count, --break=count
       Insert line breaks every count characters.  The default is 0,
       which generates an unbroken stream.
```

Knowing that, this command breaks in macOS 13 (Ventura):

```
IMAGE_BASE64=$(base64 -b0 /path/to/image.jpg);
```

But this slight variant, where there is a space between `-b` and `0` as well as the `-i` for the input file, would work:

```
IMAGE_BASE64=$(base64 -b 0 -i /path/to/image.jpg);
```

But the `-i` for the input file now seems to be required and no longer just implied by the path being the last item in the command.

What a subtly confusing headache.